# I am trying to implement ngx-bootstrap datepicker

Tags: angular

I am trying to implement ngx-bootstrap datepicker. I need to show month as Jan, Feb Mar, Apr but for now it is showing as January, Febuary like that. what to do?

Comment: Welcome to SO. I'd recommend taking [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and then reading [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as an introduction to how SO works, and how to effectively ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

You customize date format and use the momentjs formats.

Refer : https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker#format for date format customization.

Find here the moment JS formats : https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/

For example :

```
<input class="form-control"
        #datepickerYMD="bsDatepicker"
        bsDatepicker
        formControlName="dateYMD"
        [bsConfig]="{ dateInputFormat: 'DD-MMM-YYYY' }">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can customise your code following the sample example.
**[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-datepicker-month-picker-poc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**

```
onOpenCalendar(container) {
container.monthSelectHandler = (event: any): void => {
  container._store.dispatch(container._actions.select(event.date));
};     
container.setViewMode('month');
}
```